# How can I troubleshoot Neo4j HA clustering?

Tags: neo4j

I am setting up a Neo4j HA cluster according to the documentation (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/highly-available-cluster) but Neo4j does not seem to be applying the HA configuration.

I can browse to the Neo4j browser and my database is active, but :play sysinfo shows 'High Availability' = 'Not enabled' and Cluster = 'No cluster'.

I also cannot telnet to the clustering port (5001):

```
ubuntu@ip-172-0-31-71:~$ telnet localhost 5001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
ubuntu@ip-172-0-31-71:~$
```

The HA configuration in Neo4j is:

```
# Unique server id for this Neo4j instance
# can not be negative id and must be unique
ha.server_id=2

# List of other known instances in this cluster
ha.initial_hosts=neo4j-prod-1:5001,neo4j-prod-2:5001,neo4j-prod-3:5001

# HA - High Availability
# SINGLE - Single mode, default.
dbms.mode=HA
```

I'm starting the container with the following command which routes communication on the clustering port (5001) to the container:

```
/usr/bin/docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --publish=5001:5001 \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/conf:/conf \
    neo4j:3.0
```

It looks like Neo4j is not loading the HA configuration - where should I look next?

Answer (score 1):

HA does not work in Neo4j Community Edition.

To enable HA, run Enterprise Edition with:

```
/usr/bin/docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --publish=5001:5001 \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/data:/data \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    --volume=/var/lib/neo4j/conf:/conf \
    neo4j:3.0-enterprise
```